# Octokit.js not working with Vite. Module externalized and cannot be accessed in client mode

Tags: reactjs, vite, octokit, octokit-js

**What am I doing?**

I am using Vite for my React app. I'm importing Octokit and binding it like this:

```
import { Octokit } from "octokit";
const githubToken = import.meta.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN;
const octokit = new Octokit({auth: githubToken});
```

I expect this to function normally. As in, I expect to make requests using `octokit` perfectly fine.

**What am I experiencing?**

- https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5963. An issue akin to this.

Or at least, it starts with this: `Module "stream" has been externalized for browser compatibility and cannot be accessed in client code.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a credible solution, it worked for me, but it feels more like a work-around. Also, I wasn't inclined on putting enough effort to create a "minimal reproduction repo" so I wasn't able to post this as an issue on [Vite's repo](https://github.com/vitejs/vite).

Anyway, I solved `Module "stream" has been externalized for browser compatibility and cannot be accessed in client code.` by:

1. Installing `isomorphic-fetch` by `yarn add isomorphic-fetch`.
2. Changing my `vite.config.js` to alias `isomorphic-fetch` for `node-fetch`.

Modified `vite.config.js`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'node-fetch': 'isomorphic-fetch',
    },
  },
})
```

This, however, led to an issue of `Module "os" has been externalized for browser compatibility and cannot be accessed in client code.`

I fixed that by changing `import { Octokit } from "octokit";` to `import { Octokit } from "@octokit/core";`.

This led me to the next issue, `global not defined`.

Had to "fix" that by adding

```js
 define: {
    "global": {},
  },
```

to `vite.config.js`.

If you have a better solution, let me know.

Comment: Also `axios` could be used instead of `isomorphic-fetch`

Comment: yeah, essentially any drop-in replacement for `node-fetch`.