# Uncaught TypeError: import_stream.default.Readable is undefined using package @octokit/core

Tags: reactjs, api, github, vite, octokit

I'm trying to set up a environment that allows me to interact with github apis in React - Vite using @octokit/core.

I'm importing octokit in my file:

```
import { Octokit } from "@octokit/core";
```

And when I start my application using Vite I have an error message in the console: **Uncaught TypeError: import_stream.default.Readable is undefined**.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit this today too... following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73095593) helped me.
For the error you have, this part specifically helped shift it:

```
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'node-fetch': 'isomorphic-fetch',
    },
  },
})
```

(though in my case I was already using Axios, so used that instead of `isomorphic-fetch`).